# git update new repo from subtree

Tags: git

I have a tricky situation. There are two repositories involved, which we'll call `monolith` and `module`. `module` was created in Github based on a template, and therefore already contained commits. I split a subdirectory out of the monolith and merged with the new repo as follows:

```
monolith> git subtree split --prefix module --branch module-only
monolith> git push ../module module-only:module-only
monolith> cd ../module
module> git merge module-only --allow-unrelated-histories # Remember, the template commits?
```

I have since done some work on `module`, adding a few commits. I've learned that work also occurred on `monolith` in the module subdirectory. I'm being asked to update the `module` repo with the latest changes from `monolith`.

**How do I update the subtree?**

I'm answering my own question because I figured it out before I finished writing this. If you have a better answer, I'll happily give you the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but this is what I ended up doing:

```
monolith> git branch -D module-only # I couldn't seem to update the subtree...
monolith> git subtree split --prefix module --branch module-only # So just recreate it

# These steps are the same as before
monolith> git push ../module module-only:module-only
monolith> cd ../module
module> git merge module-only
```

Note that the git options `--prefix` and `--branch` can be changed to short options `-P` and `-b` respectively. I used the long options for clarity in this answer. I'm adding this note because I keep coming back to my own answer to remember the flags... lol.

---

***Things that didn't work***

My attempts to update the subtree branch by various combinations of `git subtree pull` failed.

I tried updating directly from the module-only branch:

```
module> git pull ../monolith module-only:master
```

But this was rejected for being `non-fast forward`. So I tried to merge changes into the subtree first:

```
monolith> git checkout module-only
monolith:subtree> git pull ../module master:module-only
```

This was also rejected for being `non-fast forward`. Both ahead and behind I guess?

My rebase attempts were a nightmare.